# MS-SQL get difference value

Tags: sql, coldfusion

I have this query that calculates current gallons value from all fuel tanks in my database.

```
SELECT DISTINCT y.TankNumber as TankNumber
    , y.Gallons as Gallons
    , y.timeUpdated
    , y.FuelType as FuelType
FROM (
    SELECT TankNumber, max(timeUpdated) as maxdate
    FROM someTable
    GROUP BY TankNumber) as x
JOIN someTable y
ON x.TankNumber = y.TankNumber
AND x.maxdate = y.timeUpdated
ORDER BY y.TankNumber
```

Based on the fuel usage, data gets dumped in to my database automatically at any time. And query above will give me only the current gallons value in each fueltank:

```
TankNumber  |  Gallons  |  timeUpdated        |  FuelType
     1      |  14       |  2012-10-22 04:16   |  89
     2      |  8        |  2012-10-22 04:14   |  93
```

and etc..
My problem is, that I am trying to add another output value to my page, that will give me a difference how much fuel was used since last update. So it will look something like this:

```
TankNumber  |  Gallons  |  timeUpdated        |  FuelType  |  GallonsUsed
     1      |  14       |  2012-10-22 04:16   |  89        |  5
     2      |  8        |  2012-10-22 04:14   |  93        |  -11
```

Unfortunately my SQL experience is not as solid for this type of problem and I have spent about two days trying to figure out or google something close. So, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: problem is that you're needing data that's present in other rows, which is non-trivial with sql. you'd need subqueries (probably corelated), self-joins, blah blah blah to be able to make that "other row" data visible in the current row.

Comment: Would it be easier "for me" write another query, and calculate both query values with CF?

Comment: Problem is your subquery/join only fetches the latest updated row, whereas you want "the row that was updated immediately before the row I'm on" type thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using MS SQL 2005 or later, you can use the ROW_NUMBER function:

```
WITH cteOrderedUpdates As
(
   SELECT
      TankNumber,
      Gallons,
      TimeUpdated,
      FuelType,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
      (
         PARTITION BY 
            TankNumber 
         ORDER BY 
            TimeUpdated DESC
      ) As RowNumber
   FROM
      someTable
)
SELECT
   x.TankNumber,
   x.Gallons,
   x.TimeUpdated,
   x.FuelType,
   x.Gallons - IsNull(y.Gallons, 0) As GallonsUsed
FROM
   cteOrderedUpdates As x
   LEFT JOIN cteOrderedUpdates As y
   ON x.TankNumber = y.TankNumber
   And x.RowNumber = y.RowNumber - 1
WHERE
   x.RowNumber = 1
ORDER BY
   x.TankNumber
;
```

Comment: WOW. It works :) How do you learn SQL, or it just comes with experience?

Comment: Mainly experience, I guess. SqlServerCentral.com has some good resources for getting started.